# NetworkManager doesn't show ethernet connection

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet

So after upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 16.10 I noticed that my `eth0` device had disappeared. My machine also doesn't connect to the network by default, and the connection is not shown in gnome's NetworkManager.

dmesg output reveals that the device has been renamed:

```
[    1.109498] igb 0000:26:00.0 enp38s0: renamed from eth0
```

and I can get the connection working by running `ifconfig enp38s0 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 && dhclient`.

From here, how do I

- persist this so the connection is established automatically
- get the device to show in NetworkManager

Already had a look in `/etc/network/interfaces` and neither `eth0` nor `enp38s0` are listed there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I desperately tried to find the config issues in `/etc/NetworkManager/` but didn't realise that `/usr/lib/NetworkManager` exists as well.

The problem was in `/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf`:

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan
```

I ended up removing the file completely, quick reboot and all is working again.

Comment: My Ubuntu (16.04) doesn't seem to have a conf.d subfolder in the /usr/lib location, and the only file in the /etc conf.d folder is `default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`.  Perhaps we're using different versions/distros?

Answer (score 18):

A fresh install, to server 17.10 with LXDE had this issue reading all over and trying everything. This also prevented me from using openvpn via network manager.

**The following fixed the issue:**

My `/etc/network/interfaces` file:
removed all lines except:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Then I edited `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`
from:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Add in [keyfile] string

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan,except:type:ethernet
```

**Current `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`**

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[keyfile]  
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan,except:type:ethernet

[ifupdown]
managed=true

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

**Last run command:**

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

and all showed correctly in the network manger after a couple hours of fighting! This is for a home server, it may have been caused me configuring the IP during setup, which added values for a static IP in `/etc/network/interfaces` .

Comment: For me, all the interfaces in network manager disappeared. My system won't DHCP after reboot, although would run "dhclient" manually just fine.  I tried reinstalling network manager, purging all the config files - nothing helped! Finally, this solution helped.

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly on a freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04 as well.

Comment: Thank you. it did the magick!

Comment: after hours of searching, this did the trick. thank you!

Comment: Editing `/etc/network/interfaces` and executing `systemctl restart NetworkManager` was enough for me on Debian 12. Maybe it is now the same for Debian-based Linux distributions like Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and just add `,except:type:ethernet` to `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

result is :

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan,except:type:ethernet

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

Comment: I don't have a `[keyfile]` section in my conf file.  Would it still help to add this, or is the default likely to be OK?

Comment: Yes  I think you can, if it cause problem just remove it.  I'm running 18.04  and I don't use that anymore

Answer (score 0):

Performing `sudo apt update` caused ethernet to not show in networks widget, but network connections via ethernet continued to work.
This was when `/var/log/apt` showed:

```
Preparing to unpack .../linux-firmware_1.187.10_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-firmware (1.187.10) over (1.187.9) ...
Preparing to unpack .../python3-pil_7.0.0-4ubuntu0.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-pil:amd64 (7.0.0-4ubuntu0.3) over (7.0.0-4ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up linux-firmware (1.187.10) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-66-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-65-generic
Setting up python3-pil:amd64 (7.0.0-4ubuntu0.3) ...
Log ended: 2021-03-11  13:11:10
```

I edited `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` from:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true      #Fixed this: This was "false" <<<<<<<<<

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

And I Added the missing `[keyfile]` plus devices string `<<<<<<`:

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan,except:type:ethernet
```

then I restarted NetworkManager and problem resolved. Problem was caused by linux-firmware update

Answer (score 0):

`[keyfile] unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan,except:type:ethernet`

This solved the problem for me.

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, AMD Ryzen 3900 in a Laptop.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

A lack of the `[keyfile]` entry seemed to be the issue for me on Kali 2022 running on a RasPi 4, exactly as suggested by other answers here (so kudos to the answers above!).

However, editing the `NetworkManager.conf` file can only be considered a short-term solution as that file might be replaced/updated in a package update. Even though your package manager may alert you to the conflict - `apt` usually does - rather play it safe. The more stable solution would be to use the existing `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d` directory and place your custom configuration in there. (**Note:** This is the configuration directory for a modern version of `NetworkManager` and yours *may not be the same*! Run `NetworkManager --print-config` to see where your `NetworkManager` configuration files are)

Call the file whatever you want, I opted for `99-keyfile-fix.conf`, just make sure it ends in `.conf`. All you need to add in there is the `[keyfile]` lines, so:

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan,except:type:ethernet
```

Save the file and issue `systemctl restart NetworkManager` (or `service NetworkManager restart` if you are still using that) and when `NetworkManager` re-ups, you should see your connections in there again.

As a little extra tip, if you're doing this on a desktop you can omit `except:type:wifi` if your desktop doesn't have a WiFi device. Similarly, if you don't have an Ethernet-capable device (in which case you might have landed on the wrong AskUbuntu answer anyway!) you can omit the `except:type:ethernet`.